# Setting Chance of getting Items for Random (C++)?

Tags: c++, class, random

I have 5 classes (Legendary Egg, Rare Egg, Common Egg, Dragon food, Gold). All items that are inherited from an Item class.

Supposedly, the output is that the user is playing a gacha machine where they can get any of those items. But I want to set the chance percentage of getting specific items so that it won't be so easy to get the rarer items.

```
Legendary Egg = 1%
Rare Egg = 10%
Common Egg = 20%
Dragon Food = 20%
Gold = 29%
```

What is an efficient way to do this? I put all the items in an array at first and used rand()% but I realized that I couldn't set the chance of getting them. I thought of using something like

```
if (value < 0.1){
std:: cout << "You got a legendary egg!";
}
```

but I felt that it would be a bit inefficient because I was told to avoid blocks of if else.

*The items are in their own (separate) class because they have different abilities

Comment: Why would this be inefficient?

Comment: _but I felt that it would be a bit inefficient._ Why did you feel that way?

Comment: "because I was told to avoid blocks of if else" what? why?

Comment: @DimChtz editted! My teacher also told me that it could be tedious to keep writing if else and that there could be better and more efficient ways because I could have 100 items.

Comment: Well you could use a switch statement if you had more check on the same variable, but it's not your case. So I don't see the problem.

Comment: Sometimes (most of the times) you have to ignore your teacher. Just saying ...

Comment: @Confused.Student you don't "keep writing" them. Just roll once with the if-else chain. Try to handle everything in there (message, roll for specific sub-class, add to inventory etc.). If you can't handle everything in there you can always create an enum class for item category and pass that as an argument to any function that needs it.

Comment: Also see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/big-picture#defn-evil for why you can't obsess over "never use..." statements.

Comment: Shouldn't your percentages add up to 100%, not 80%?

Comment: @ChrisDrew: Seems there's an implicit 20% chance of not getting anything.

Answer (score 7):

The modern C++ way [see](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::discrete_distribution<> d({1, 10, 20, 20, 29, 20});

    std::map<int, int> m;
    for(int n=0; n<10000; ++n) {
        ++m[d(gen)];
    }
    for(auto p : m) {
        std::cout << p.first << " generated " << p.second << " times\n";
    }
}
```

Simply call `d(gen)`to get one item with your desired distribution ( 0 = 'Legendary Egg' and so on).

Note: the values are weights. You talked about percent. That should add up to 100, so I added another 20%.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to convert the per-outcome percentages into a joint table

`{0.01, 0.01 + 0.10, 0.01 + 0.10 + 0.20, ... }`

Now generate a number between 0 and 1 and see between which two borders it falls. Generating the table is simple; you use `std::partial_sum` for that. Looking up the result in the table is also easy, that's the job of `std::upper_bound`.

E.g. 0.15 lies between `0.01 + 0.10` and `0.01 + 0.10 + 0.20`, so `upper_bound` will find the iterator for `0.01 + 0.10 + 0.20`. It's easy to see this happens with 20% chance, as intended.